# Issue in using Switch Case on Union Types + Mapped Types

Tags: typescript, switch-statement, typescript-typings, react-typescript

TypeScript compiler is not able to figure out type of argument (action.payload) based on actionType in following code snippet -

```
enum Actions{
ACTIONA,
ACTIONB
};

type ActionA = {
  type : Actions.ACTIONA,
  payload: {
    body: string;
    message: object;
  }
}

type ActionB = {
  type : Actions.ACTIONB,
  payload: {
    message: object;
  }
}

type ActionType = ActionA | ActionB;

const actionHandlers: {
  [key in  Actions.ACTIONA | Actions.ACTIONB]: (payload: Extract<ActionType, { type: key }>['payload']) => void
} = {
  [Actions.ACTIONA]: ({body, message}) => console.log(body, message),
  [Actions.ACTIONB]: ({message}) => console.log( message),
}

const performAction = (action: ActionType): void => {
  switch(action.type){
    case Actions.ACTIONA:
    case Actions.ACTIONB:
      return actionHandlers[action.type](action.payload); 
  }
}
```

Error -

```
Argument of type '{ body: string; message: object; } | { message: object; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ body: string; message: object; }'.
  Property 'body' is missing in type '{ message: object; }' but required in type '{ body: string; message: object; }'
```

Thanks in Advance!

One Way to fix is by repeating case body for both cases. But in real code scenarios, case body can be huge and repeating it again and again is not the best way to solve this.

```
case Actions.ACTIONA:
   return actionHandlers[action.type](action.payload); 
case Actions.ACTIONB:
   return actionHandlers[action.type](action.payload);
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `switch`/`case` with this example; don't you want to call `actionHandlers[action.type](action.payload)` no matter what `action.type` is? If not, could you show that? Anyway, the issue is TS's inability to deal with *correlated union types* and there's a recommended refactoring to generics that looks like [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/Wy6abw) (assuming `switch`/`case` is unneeded). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls ping me via @jcalz if you reply)

Comment: AFAIK, TypeScript isn't able to detect the type of "action" based on a tuple, which is what you're looking for. I agree it makes sense to us as humans, though. With the fix you found, it is able to detect the type of "action" using narrowing. If you want to fix this, you could make the type of "payload" to have body as an optional property, but that does change the meaning of the two types as well

Comment: @jcalz there is a lot of other code as well in the case body and there are a lot of other cases in the real place where I'm facing this issue. 

Actually, I have simplified the code just for easy understanding of the problem.

Let's just say for our case, it won't be possible to avoid cases/switch statements.

Comment: If you could show just a single situation where the switch/case is needed, it would help.  Like, does [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mx848m) demonstrate it?  If so, could you edit that in? If not, could you edit *some* situation in so that I can be sure that my suggestion works in that situation?  Thanks.  (And ping me via @jcalz when you're done, if you take my suggestion)

Answer (score -1):

I find that most of the time, it's actually easier for me to just type cast the inner implementation since that part *doesn't actually* need to be type safe. Since `actionHandlers` and your `actions` are already type safe, I think this would be perfectly acceptable:

```
const performAction = (action: ActionType): void => {
  return (actionHandlers[action.type] as any)(action.payload);
}
```

Not related to the question, but just a small nit.

```
// you can do this instead
const actionHandlers: {
  [key in ActionType['type']]: (payload: Extract<ActionType, { type: key }>['payload']) => void
} = ...
```

rather than listing out each action (you've already done this with the `ActionType` type.